# Update Identity database with entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

as i am using asp.net identity and entity framework in same project now i am adding the field in aspnet User table and adding the migration it throws error like "Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel."

i had tried force update verbose and everything

public string UserRole { get; set; }
field should be added in the aspnet user table

Comment: Please share your code, DataContext, entities and mappings

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: are you trying to update your model with existing db ?